# get offline access_token from instagram api to get users images

Tags: php, api, instagram, social-networking

Hi is this possible to get access_token in instagram api without login.
I am using server side script that will receive a user name of instagram like "snoopdog" and then my script will get photos of snoopdog from instagram api. but when i am trying to generate access_token it is asking me to login on instagram.

i am using this url to get photos.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/media/recent?access_token=3160711211.5b9e1e6.3b523f746c7c487f8f63743f15e16180
```

But if i want to generate access_token every time i need to login ?
is there any other way to get offline access token ?

Comment: did u figure out how to do it? in case of public pages

Comment: @Yerken you can't do without login.

Comment: this approach seems to be working for public pages, though cannot find any documentation related to this  https://www.instagram.com/smena8m/media/

Answer (score 0):

To get access token, you need to login and give permission to your client.